# Action always going to Index using submit()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view, I'm using a function, `submitForm(action)` to submit the form on button click. This is one of many buttons that will use this function. The `action` parameter will indicate which controller method to use.

The function seems to generate the correct Action attribute (the path is correct in the console), but it is always directed to the `Index` method rather than the `action` parameter.

The button:

`<input type="button" value="Save Only" id="save" onclick="submitForm('SaveOnly')" />`

The function:

```
function submitForm(action) {
    var $form = $("#myForm"); 
    $form.action = ("/Area/MyController/" + action);
    $form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the 'action' attribute of the form itself, but to the jQuery selector result, in order for your code to work, you need to access the DOM element from inside the selector with $form[0].
I recommend to stick to jQuery, you're already using it!. Below is a working code with jQuery selectors.

`<form id="myForm"></form>
    <input type="button" value="Save Only" id="save" data-action="saveOnly"  />`

```
<script>

$('#save').click(function(){
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var $form = $("#myForm");
    $form.attr('action', "www.google.com?q=" + action);
    $form.attr('method', 'GET');
    $form.submit();
});

</script>
```